# Why does this Python script delete '.txt' files, as well as all the '.tmp' files?

Tags: python, python-2.7, os.walk, os.path

I'm trying to write a script that will automatically delete all the temp files in a specific folder, and I noticed that this script also deletes all the *text files* in that folder as well. Can anyone explain why it does that?

```
   import os
   path = 'C:\scripts27'
   for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
       for currentFile in files:
           print "processing file: " + currentFile
           extensions=('.tmp')
           if any(currentFile.lower().endswith(ext) for ext in extensions):
               os.remove(os.path.join(root, currentFile))
```

I'm running this script using Python 2.7.10 on a Windows 8.1 PC 64-bit.

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm assuming you meant providing a list of extensions. But in your case, `extensions` is defined as `('.tmp')` which is *not* a tuple but a string. This causes your code to loop over all files and check for names ending with `.`, `t`, `m` and `p` thereby deleting your `.txt` files.

The fix here is to define extensions as `['.tmp']` or `('.tmp',)` (notice the trailing `,`).

Comment: That's it! Thank you.

Comment: @Basper82 - ```if currentFile.lower().endswith('.tmp'): do stuff```.